# Refer to class inside of static method without using its name

Tags: javascript, class, static

How can I refer to a class  from a static method without using the class name itself in JavaScript (similar to PHP's `self` and `self::method_name`)?

For example, in the class below, how can I refer to the method `foo` and the method `bar` inside of the `foobar` method **without the use of** `FooBar.methodName`?

```
class FooBar {
    static foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    static bar() {
        return 'bar';
    }

    static foobar() {
        return FooBar.foo() + FooBar.bar(); 
        // self::foo() + self::bar() would have been more desirable.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword to refer to the object itself.

See example below:

```js
class FooBar {
  static foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }

  static bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }

  static foobar() {
    return this.foo() + this.bar();
    // self::foo() + self::bar() would have been more desirable.
  }
}

const res = FooBar.foobar();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes: the syntax you're asking about is "this".

From MDN:

> https://medium.com/@yyang0903/static-objects-static-methods-in-es6-1c026dbb8bb1
>
> As MDN describes it, “Static methods are called without instantiating
>   their class and are also not callable when the class is instantiated.
>   Static methods are often used to create utility functions for an
>   application.” In other words, static methods have no access to data
>   stored in specific objects.
>   ...
>
> Note that for static methods, the `this` keyword references the class.
>   You can call a static method from another static method within the
>   same class with this.

Also note:

> There are two ways to call static methods:
>
> ```
> Foo.methodName() 
> // calling it explicitly on the Class name
> // this would give you the actual static value. 
>
> this.constructor.methodName()
> // calling it on the constructor property of the class
> // this might change since it refers to the class of the current instance, where the static property could be overridden
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If all of those methods are static then you can use `this`.

```
class FooBar {
    static foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    static bar() {
        return 'bar';
    }

    static foobar() {
        return this.foo() + this.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if all of them aren't static and the class has a constructor?

Comment: Then you can't, at least not as easily. Mixing static and non-static method access is more complicated.